# How can I efficiently query 'Like' data from MySQL?

Tags: mysql

I am developing a social network iOS app using a PHP backend with a MySQL database. I have 3 tables in my database to store Posts, Comments and Likes.

Currently, the app requests up to 50 posts at a time which includes various specific data. I do this using a SELECT query from MySQL. My 'Likes' are stored in the 'Likes table' as 1 Like per row. This includes their username and which post they 'liked'.

When the app is refreshed, I need to gather the 'Likes' data on the posts that have just been loaded. My problem is that I do not know the best way to query MySQL to return all associated likes with that user. This means that when I load some posts, I want the user to see which posts they have already liked.

Here is a visual description of my problem:
[image: Here is a visual description of my problem]

Please understand that up to 50 of these posts will be shown at one time.

Comment: Please add your table definitions and the SELECT queries you tried.

Comment: Don't show pictures, show table definitions with indexes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is several way to do this and depending on your project you might want to optimise my answer.

I assume your `Likes` table has a structure of `(int) id, (int) user_id, (int) post_id`.

To answer directly to your question (about doing a query only for the refresh), the next MySQL query will give you the list of `post_id` liked by the user. You need to replace `%user_id%` by the id of the user and `%post_ids%` by the list of the 50 posts ids, separated by a comma:

```
SELECT post_id
FROM Likes
WHERE user_id = %user_id% AND
      post_id IN (%post_ids%)
```

However, if the refresh implies the whole page (and not only an AJAX request or so on) I would consider implementing this directly in the query getting the posts. For example :

```
SELECT p.id, p.content, p...., l.id AS `Liked`
FROM Posts AS p
LEFT JOIN Likes AS l
       ON p.id = l.post_id AND
          l.user_id = %user_id%  
WHERE ...
```

Please also consider adding indexes on the right columns.

Comment: Thank you very much. The second piece of code you gave there was very helpful. I will update once I have implemented and tested!

Comment: Thanks again, I have added my solution below :)

Answer (score 0):

As promised, my solution is here:

```
SELECT `posts`.`postnumber`, `posts`.`message`, `likes`.`didLike`
FROM `posts`
LEFT JOIN `likes`
ON `posts`.`postnumber`=`likes`.`post_id`
AND `likes`.`user_id`='USERNAME';
```